# How to find a correlation between a numeric variable and a factor variable in R?

Tags: r

I am new to R and I am trying to find run both a correlation and a t-test between a numerical variable and a factor variable. The factor variable is gender (F, M) and the numerical variable is weight. How do I do this?

I tried with cor.test(weight, gender) and 
t.test(weight, gender)but kept getting errors.

These are the errors:

> cor.test(weight, gender)
>   Error in cor.test.default(weight, gender) : 
>     'x' and 'y' must have the same length

and:

> t.test(weight, gender)
>   Error in var(y) : Calling var(x) on a factor x is defunct.
>     Use something like 'all(duplicated(x)[-1L])' to test for a constant vector.
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In mean.default(y) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do here is to form a vector of weights where Gender = M and Gender = F, and then run the t.test function on these vectors. This is because a t-test between "gender" (treated as a 0/1 integer) and "weight" would be statistically illogical. This will require subsetting your data.

I will use ChickWeights here as an example, since it has both a Weight (numeric) and Diet (factor) variables. i.e. :

```
str(ChickWeights)
```

We will imagine that chicks on the first diet are males and chicks on the second diet are females.

```
m_weights <- ChickWeight$weight[ChickWeight$Diet == 2]
f_weights <- ChickWeight$weight[ChickWeight$Diet == 3]
```

You can then run the t-test.

```
t.test(x = m_weights,y = f_weights)
```

If you want to correlate the variables "gender" and "weight", you will need to use something other than a standard correlation test - e.g. a [Point-biserial correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-biserial_correlation_coefficient).

You could also do a correlation test between the paired groups of males and females by subsetting the data appropriately (the vectors would need to be equal length). This, however would not likely be logical based on how I understand the structure of your data. Nonetheless, here is how to do that:

```
ChickWeight_filt <- ChickWeight[ChickWeight$Diet %in% c(1,2) & ChickWeight$Time %in% c(0,2) & ChickWeight$Chick %in% c(1:10,21:30),]


m_weights_filt <- ChickWeight_filt$weight[ChickWeight_filt$Diet == 1]
f_weights_filt <- ChickWeight_filt$weight[ChickWeight_filt $Diet == 2]

cor.test(x = as.numeric(m_weights_filt),y = as.numeric(f_weights_filt))
```

If you have follow questions around statistics as a result of this, you might be best to ask here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/